# Warning with @ConfigurationProperties Annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I Can see the following warning with @ConfigurationProperties Annotation

`When using @ConfigurationProperties it is recommended to add 'spring-boot-configuration-processor' to your classpath to generate configuration metadata`

Everything working fine. What it meant for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add an optional dependency to the “spring-boot-configuration-processor”, your module will hold a meta-data file that is generated at compile time with details about your properties. IDEs can then pick that up to show you content assist/auto-completion. STS, Intellij IDEA and Netbeans have such support . 
It is an annotation processor that generates metadata about classes in your application that are annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties`.

More info here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-metadata

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor